# Atom não acha o PHP

Tags: php, atom

eu estou testando o atom mas ao instalar o plugin atom-beautify ele funciona em todas as linguagens porém quando eu tento identar em PHP ele me da esse erro.

> Could not find 'PHP'. The program may not be installed.
>
> See http://php.net/manual/en/install.php for program installation
>   instructions. You can configure Atom Beautify with the absolute path
>   to 'php' by setting 'Executable - PHP - Path' in the Atom Beautify
>   package settings. Your program is properly installed if running 'which
>   PHP' in your Terminal returns an absolute path to the executable. If
>   this does not work then you have not installed the program correctly
>   and so Atom Beautify will not find the program. Atom Beautify requires
>   that the program be found in your PATH environment variable.  Note
>   that this is not an Atom Beautify issue if beautification does not
>   work and the above command also does not work: this is expected
>   behaviour, since you have not properly installed your program. Please
>   properly setup the program and search through existing Atom Beautify
>   issues before creating a new issue. See
>   https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/search?q=PHP&type=Issues
>   for related Issues and
>   https://github.com/Glavin001/atom-beautify/tree/master/docs for
>   documentation. If you are still unable to resolve this issue on your
>   own then please create a new issue and ask for help.
>
> -Hide Stack Trace
>
> Error: Could not find 'PHP'. The program may not be installed.
>       at Function.Executable.commandNotFoundError (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/executable.coffee:264:14)
>       at HybridExecutable.Executable.commandNotFoundError (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/executable.coffee:256:18)
>       at /home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/src/beautifiers/executable.coffee:115:25
>       at tryCatcher (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:512:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:569:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:614:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:689:18)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:133:16)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:10)
>       at Async.drainQueues (/home/edsonlima/.atom/packages/atom-beautify/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

Mas o php esta instalado corretamente, o que pode ser alguém sabe ?

Comment: Em que sistema operacional vc esta trabalhando? ja checou se o php esta no path?

Comment: Estou usando o ubuntu-Gnome, esse comando por acaso seria which php, se sim já, se não como faço ?

Comment: Tente esse comando: `php -r 'echo function_exists("test") ? "yes" : "no";'` o resultado terá que ser `no`, ou então instale o apache (se já não tiver instalado) e, no browser, tente acessar `localhost`.

Comment: Outor comando que vc pode tentar: `whereis php`, o resultado teria que ser algo como: `php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/php7.0 /usr/lib/php /etc/php /usr/share/php7.0-mysql ....`

Answer (score 1):

Agora o Atom Editor se transformou no Atom IDE e esta incrível graças a uma comunidade ativa do Facebook: o [Nuclide](https://nuclide.io/).

Faça seguinte:

- Instale este pacote: https://atom.io/packages/atom-ide-ui
- Agora instale a sua linguagem predileta: [ide-php](https://github.com/atom/ide-php/)

Existe outras lingaugens para envenenar o seu Atom. Para mais, [confira este link](http://binariux.com.br/seja-bem-vindo-ao-atom-ide/).